# Tool for finding illegal CSS selectors

Tags: css

Are there any tools that can be used to check and see if any malformed selectors are being used in a stylesheet, such as

```
div:fifth-child {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

We are looking for a tool that will find these in a file.

Thank you.

Comment: there is no tool for that you hould use css cheatsheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the [W3C CSS Validation Service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

It flags your example with the error "Unknown pseudo-element or pseudo-class :fifth-child".

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I used [Dust Me](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/). It will find *unused* CSS selectors.

**Note:** While a malformed or invalid CSS selectors will likely be *unused*, this tool may not match your requirements exactly. I, nonetheless, found it useful in combination with [W3C CSS Validation Service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Answer (score 0):

there is no tool for that but u can check them through browser addons or validate ur site in http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

and if you use firefox there is firefox extension which tells css and html error its a great extension you can download it here for firefox

http://www.htmlvalidator.com/firefoxext.php

Comment: The validator you mention _is_ a tool...

Comment: its a site which checks css validation

Comment: That's right. In other words it is one of the _tools_ available to web developers...

Comment: there is extention for firefox who also checks thisu can download it there http://www.htmlvalidator.com/firefoxext.php